# Cucumber JVM + Espresso - the html report is not only showing scenario titles, but not steps

Tags: android, cucumber-jvm, android-espresso

I am using Cucumber JVM in Android Studio with Espresso test automation framework.

But, when I tried to export the report html, it only shows me the title of the scenarios, but not steps that failed / passed.

I am using Cucumber annotation in my step definition class as shown below.

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "features")
public class TestStepDef extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

}
```

When I tried to add the json formatter in my `CucumberOptions` annotation like below, the test runs, but says empty test suite.

```
@CucumberOptions(
    format = 
        {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report", "json:target/cucumber-report.json"}, 
    features = "features")
```

Comment: Any update on this? html report generation working for you?